# Using question mark character in Rails/ActiveRecord column name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In keeping with Ruby's idiom of using a question mark in boolean methods (e.g. `person.is_smart?`), I'd like to do the same for an ActiveRecord field in Rails:

```
rails generate model Person is_smart?:boolean
```

I haven't actually run the above statement. I assume that database fields can't have a question mark in them. Will rails deal with this appropriately? Is the best practice to simply leave question marks off of models?

Using Rails 3.2.8

Comment: Why not just call it `smart` and then add custom accessors so you can say `is_smart?` when you're talking to an actual Person?

Comment: @matt - I guess that makes the most sense since it's not common that you would name a boolean variable with a question mark at the end and we would be treating the above `is_smart?` as a variable.

Comment: Rails is your friend. See Cdesrosiers' answer.

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Rails will automatically generate the method `smart?` if there is a field named `'smart'`.

Comment: Actually Rails generates `?` methods for all columns. They appear to return true only if the value is truthy. So this is a perfect match for booleans.

Comment: Actually, Kelvin's comment above is almost right. It returns true if the value is `present?`, not truthy. So "" returns false, for example.

Comment: Is there any documentation for the semantics of the question-mark form?

Comment: never have been i so wrong. also thought it would just check for `present?` https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/query.rb#L10

Comment: ...and remember: it is a bad practice in rails to set prefixes like 'is_' or 'has_' in yours methods and columns https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37059547/naming-conventions-for-boolean-attributes#answer-37060624

Comment: ..and, until is a bad practice, actually it is possible at least in PosgreSQL and MySQL, to use question marks in the columns names which is very painful to use when you write it in a statement.

Comment: Surprisingly, for numeric attributes, the question mark helper checks for 0. If user.level is 0, then user.level? is false but user.level.present? is true!

Answer (score 6):

One "gotcha" to be aware of if you happen to use `:enum` in your model, since this stores the value as an integer. The question mark attr method provided by active record expects to evaluate 0 or 1 as false / true respectively in the database. For example:

```
class Person
  enum mood: ['happy', 'sad', 'bored']
end

p = Person.new(mood: 'happy') # this would store mood as 0 in db
p.mood? #=> false

p.mood = 'sad' # saves as 1 in db
p.mood? #=> true

p.mood = 'bored' # saves as 2 in db
p.mood? #=> true
```

to see how this method works, see [rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/query.rb#L10)

Answer (score 2):

From documentation: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Attribute+query+methods

> In addition to the basic accessors, query methods are also automatically available on the Active Record object. Query methods allow you to test whether an attribute value is present. Additionally, when dealing with numeric values, a query method will return false if the value is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Im using Rails 4 and I can't call my boolean column without the question mark

```
pry(main)> User.where(is_validated: false).first.is_validated
  User Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_validated" = 'f' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> nil
[13] pry(main)> User.where(is_validated: false).first.is_validated?
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."is_validated" = 'f' ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> false
```

Comment: I made an "ask/ answer" post on this topic after this answer, but I kept this as I think this information might be valuable for deciding how to name a bool column as well.

Comment: its not that you cant call boolean cols without question mark. Its actually showing the actual value you stored in the col. add `null: false, default: false` clause in the migration.