# Naming conventions for boolean attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, attributes, naming-conventions

I want to write code that others easily can understand as well.

Do boolean attributes like `hide_email` or `email_hidden` have a convention style?

Comment: The question mark is a good system for boolean methods, but it can't be used in variable names.

Comment: variables names like those defined as `attr_accessor` just omit`?`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I think of it like this:

- A boolean attribute should answer a simple yes/no question.
- Asking "is?" is a simple way to ask a yes/no question.
- So a boolean attribute name should complete the sentence `is <attribute_name>`
- Then just remove the `is` because Ruby prefers the `?` suffix for "is"-style method names (see below for more), leaving you with just `email_hidden`

So, for your specific case, name your attribute like this:

- Start with the question "email is hidden"?. Which can be represented in code as: `email_is_hidden`.
- Remove the `is` and you're left with `email_hidden`
- Ruby on Rails defines a "predicate" version (one that ends in a `?`) of your boolean attribute and returns `true`/`false` as expected. So, while your attribute is named `email_hidden` in the database you should reference it as `email_hidden?` in your code for clarity and as is the Ruby on Rails convention.

Comment: I like the suggestion here to drop the "is" from the attribute name. I was on the fence with this one for years as you hear mixed advice in best practices. But I think dropping it makes it a little cleaner, even if it sounds less like a sentence. e.g. `user.email_hidden?` vs `user.email_is_hidden?`. To be fair, as long as you're consistent in your code base, either should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

Taking these two examples of names you gave:

- `hide_email` would be a good name for a method performing such a task, a method that executes all the procedures to hide an email in the scope of your system. But it would never be a good name for a boolean method returning the state of an e-mail.
- `email_hidden?`, with a question mark (?) at the end, would be the correct name for a boolean method indicating if the e-mail is hidden or not.

Always consider Ruby conventions if you really want to write good code. They will help you even when thinking about the processes in your system.

Comment: Question marks can't be in variables, only method names

Comment: @maxpleaner Well said. I edited it to insert the word "method" after boolean.

Comment: Great point that `hide_email` is more of a _verb_ instead of an _adjective_. i.e. it sounds like an _action_, not a _property_.

Answer (score 2):

That would be `email_hidden?`. It is what Ruby community got used to.

Please note the `?` at the end.

Comment: I assume you don't mean to save the attribute with a question mark? I know that in Rails you can call all attributes with a question mark.

Comment: I see what you mean. I thought you had a boolean attribute that other would want to query. No, you don't want to use `email_hidden` or `email_hidden?` as a setter method. You would want to use a verb like `hide_email` for a method that hides it and `email_hidden=` to allow others to set it for you.

Comment: They way you asked the question... it seems you are talking about a boolean method to check the state of an email, not about a method to execute the procedures of hiding it and return true in case of success and false in case of failure.

Answer (score 2):

The ruby code smeels said that all boolean methods should finish with ?

On active record you could see

```
User.valid?
```

Or in ruby you could find

```
[].nil?
[].empty?
```

If you want to know about Ruby's conventions read this

http://blogs.visoftinc.com/2010/04/12/ruby-beauty-method-naming-conventions/

Comment: In ruby you can also see `obj.is_a?(Something)` or `hash.has_key?(:foo)`. that's to say it's acceptable to use `is_XXX?` or `has_XXX?` when you refer to `self`