# In Rails' ActiveRecord, what does a question mark at the end of a method name corresponding to a column do?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

If `Person` is a Rails ActiveRecord class, and `name` is a table column with a type of string, then `Person#name?` doesn't seem to correspond to whether or not `name` is truthy. For example, if `name` is set to an empty string, the string is truthy, but `name?` returns false, at least for Rails 3.2.x. What does adding a question mark do?

I tried searching for this, but question marks aren't very googleable, or even symbolhoundable.

[An answer to "Using question mark character in Rails/ActiveRecord column name"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12559261/38765) mentions that ActiveRecord automatically adds question marks to field (column?) names, but there are conflicting comments on what it does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will return `true` if a field is `present?` or not. So an empty string `""` will return false.

Comment: Is there documentation confirming this?

Comment: Tried it empirically, and this seems to be the case.

Comment: Actually there is documentation disconfirming this: https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#class-ActiveRecord::Base-label-Attribute+query+methods

Answer (score 1):

The question mark methods are similar to `present?` but not the same. For instance, numeric values will return true if they aren't zero, whereas `0.present?` returns `true`. Here's the [line in the Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.2.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/query.rb#L25).